# API.ai - return input value from fallback intent

Tags: nlp, fallback, dialogflow-es, facebook-chatbot, api-ai

i am building a facebook messenger chatbot with API.ai and i want to build a fallback intent. I want to use this fallback intent for all user inputs that are not matched by any regular intent.

I would like to responde with something like "sorry, couldnt read that" + the users input.
My question: How do i get the users input and give it back as a response?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Fulfillment option in "Default Fallback Intent".

You configure your webhook pointing to your own server and there you can receive the "resolvedQuery" and return the response you want, including the user input.

Comment: thank you, working perfect now, didnt use resolvedQuery at first!